# Leave out some rows in Order to create "average" Google Chart API

Tags: javascript, graph, google-visualization

i'm trying to display an average **and** all the data in 2 lines with the Google Chart API. For example we can take this code:

```
   var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Year', 'something', 'something - Average'],
      ['2004',  1000,      400],
      ['2005',  1170,      /*leave this out*/],
      ['2006',  660,       /*leave this out*/],
      ['2007',  1030,      700]
    ]);
```

These aren't the real values of course. But what I want to achieve is that (in this example) the average of the first year, get's connected to the one of the last year in the graph and that the other values are still getting displayed. At the moment I tried it with zeros instead of `/*leave this out*/` but that is pushing down my graph.

Speaking visually, I want to achieve something similar to this: [image: example]

I just want to know what I have to insert into the array (or which options I have to make) in Order to achieve these 2 lines.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried adding `interpolateNulls: true` to your [configuration options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#configuration-options)?

Answer (score 0):

```
interpolateNulls: true;
```

in the options fixed it.